# How to reset scroll values, NO_SCROLL_RESET, Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me, scroll

I need to reset the values from scrolling, I has implemented a tabbar (developing in Blackberry OS 6), with Vertical Scroll in VerticalFieldManager, but when I select another field(tab) the Vertical Scroll return me a nullpointer, the tab code is fine, so I guess is because the first scroll event saved the items lenght from the first field (tab) and when the lenght is less than the first one give me a nullpointer, I need Reset the values from scroll when I finish scrolling, I saw this

```
(Mannager.NO_SCROLL_RESET)
```

but it's deprecated. I'm using OS 6 but the tabbar must work for every devices.

```
public class CustomizeTabbar extends MainScreen {

private int Resolucion;
VerticalFieldManager lista;
private AbsoluteFieldManager tab1Manager;
private AbsoluteFieldManager tab2Manager;
private AbsoluteFieldManager tab3Manager;
private AbsoluteFieldManager tab4Manager;
private AbsoluteFieldManager tab5Manager;  ///Detalle Nota

private AbsoluteFieldManager tabArea;
private String Token;

public CustomizeTabbar(int Res, String token) {

    Resolucion=Res;
    this.Token=token;

    try{
        ///Cabecera Tabbar
        HorizontalFieldManager htabbar= new HorizontalFieldManager(NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL|NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL|USE_ALL_WIDTH ){
            //define width
            public int getPreferredWidth()
            {
                if(Resolucion==1)
                    return 320;
                else
                    return 480;
            }
            //define height
            public int getPreferredHeight()
            {
                if(Resolucion==1)
                    return 25;
                else
                    return 36;

            }
            protected void sublayout( int maxWidth, int maxHeight )
            {
                super.sublayout(getPreferredWidth(), 
                        getPreferredHeight());
                setExtent(getPreferredWidth(), getPreferredHeight());
            }
        };

        final BitmapButtonField tab1= new BitmapButtonField(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("1notasactuales.png"),Bitmap.getBitmapResource("1notasactualesfocus.png"),FOCUSABLE);
        final BitmapButtonField tab2= new BitmapButtonField(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("1inasistencia.png"),Bitmap.getBitmapResource("1inasistenciafocus.png"),FOCUSABLE);
        final BitmapButtonField tab3= new BitmapButtonField(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("1Horario.png"),Bitmap.getBitmapResource("1HorarioFocus.png"),FOCUSABLE);
        final BitmapButtonField tab4= new BitmapButtonField(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("1record.png"),Bitmap.getBitmapResource("1recordfocus.png"),FOCUSABLE);
        LabelField spacer1 = new LabelField(" | ", LabelField.NON_FOCUSABLE);
         LabelField spacer2 = new LabelField(" | ", LabelField.NON_FOCUSABLE);
         LabelField spacer3 = new LabelField(" | ", LabelField.NON_FOCUSABLE);

        ///Controlador del Tabbar
        FieldChangeListener click=new FieldChangeListener() {

            public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {

                lista=null;
                if(tabArea!=null){
                try{
                    if(field==tab1)
                    {
                        delete(tabArea);
                        tabArea=NotasActualesDisplay();
                        add(tabArea);
                    }else 
                        if(field==tab2)
                        {
                            delete(tabArea);
                            tabArea = InasistenciaDisplay();
                            add(tabArea);
                        }else 
                            if(field==tab3)
                            {
                                delete(tabArea);
                                tabArea = HorarioDisplay();
                                add(tabArea);
                            }else
                                if(field==tab4)
                                {
                                    delete(tabArea);
                                    tabArea=RecordAcademicoDisplay();
                                    add(tabArea);
                                }
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
                }

            }
        };
        tab1.setChangeListener(click);
        tab2.setChangeListener(click);
        tab3.setChangeListener(click);
        tab4.setChangeListener(click);

        htabbar.add(tab1);
        htabbar.add(spacer1);
        htabbar.add(tab2);
        htabbar.add(spacer2);
        htabbar.add(tab3);
        htabbar.add(spacer3);
        htabbar.add(tab4);

        Background bg = BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("2tabbar_pages.png"));
        htabbar.setBackground(bg);

        setTitle(htabbar);
        /////////
        tabArea = NotasActualesDisplay();
        add(tabArea);



    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

}
  public AbsoluteFieldManager NotasActualesDisplay() {
    final VerticalFieldManager lista=new     VerticalFieldManager(Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL|Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR|Manager.NO_SCROLL_RESET){
 /* Here I design the elements with JSON using FOR*/
    }
return tab1Manager;
 }
public AbsoluteFieldManager InasistenciaDisplay() {
    VerticalFieldManager(Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL|Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR|Manager.NO_SCROLL_RESET){
 /* Here I design the elements with JSON using FOR*/
    }
return tab2Manager;
 }
public AbsoluteFieldManager HorarioDisplay() {
    VerticalFieldManager(Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL|Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR|Manager.NO_SCROLL_RESET){
 /* Here I design the elements with JSON using FOR*/
    }
 }
return tab3Manager;    
 }
```

Comment: This is too much code.  Try to make a smaller test app that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Done, only the first part is the importat, the rest is only the functions to call. TY @Michael_Donohue

Comment: I didn't get are you using `VerticalFieldManager` or `AbsoluteFieldManager`? As well are you getting error NPE when you call getVerticalScroll for VFM?

Comment: I'm using VFM with the name "Lista" this should be Vertical scroll and is the container for the elments, the AFM is the container for the VFM. The scenary is, I'm in one field(tab) and I scroll trough the elements (example 6 elements) but then when I select other field (tab) and this tab  only have example 5 elements and I start scrolling, the scroll doesn't stop in the 5 element, And there is when i get the NPE, so I think the app save the lenght scroll of the    first tab scrolled...